# Inject Ebean datasource when running SBT task

Tags: java, scala, playframework, sbt, ebean

I am trying to run Java code as an SBT task in my Play 2 application. Everything is working fine right now but when I try to access the database, it all goes wrong.

My **build.sbt** looks like this now:

```
import java.net.URLClassLoader
def registerTask(name: String, taskClass: String, description: String) = {
  val sbtTask = (dependencyClasspath in Runtime) map { (deps) =>
    val depURLs = deps.map(_.data.toURI.toURL).toArray
    val classLoader = new URLClassLoader(depURLs, null)
    val task = classLoader.
      loadClass(taskClass).
      newInstance().
      asInstanceOf[Runnable]
    task.run()
  }
  TaskKey[Unit](name, description) := sbtTask.dependsOn(compile in Compile).value
}
registerTask("generate_db", "tasks.DatabaseGenerator", "Calling DatabaseGenerator from SBT")
```

I get this error when I am trying to execute a query using Ebean.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No DataSourceFactory service implementation found in class path. Probably missing dependency to avaje-datasource?
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultContainer.getDataSourceFromConfig(DefaultContainer.java:298)
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultContainer.setDataSource(DefaultContainer.java:262)
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultContainer.createServer(DefaultContainer.java:105)
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultContainer.createServer(DefaultContainer.java:77)
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultContainer.createServer(DefaultContainer.java:44)
    at com.avaje.ebean.EbeanServerFactory.create(EbeanServerFactory.java:55)
    at com.avaje.ebean.Ebean$ServerManager.getWithCreate(Ebean.java:201)
    at com.avaje.ebean.Ebean$ServerManager.<init>(Ebean.java:159)
    at com.avaje.ebean.Ebean$ServerManager.<init>(Ebean.java:124)
    at com.avaje.ebean.Ebean.<clinit>(Ebean.java:118)
    at tasks.DatabaseGenerator.<clinit>(DatabaseGenerator.java:22)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
```

I understand the problem but I don't know how to fix it. I need to somehow inject my normal server application so that it can reach the Ebean Datasource but my Scala knowledge is null. Anyone know how to do this? Any other way to write the task?

I just want to run code from the command line without having to start up the server and running it via an HTTP request. I use this to generate SQL scripts to seed my database from .csv files.

Comment: exception says that you're missing avaje-datasource dependency, could you add it?like this libraryDependencies += "org.avaje" % "avaje-datasource" % "2.1.1"

Comment: Not really, I tried adding it into build.sbt in several places but that doesn't help, same problem. The application has all these dependencies but since I'm hacking the classpath I need to add something more in there to make sbt startup my db dependency. I have no idea how. Other maven dependencies like csv-parsers and such work. Its just that the db pool isn't started.